# How to centrally managing e-mail for multiple domains using Google Apps?

Tags: email, domain, authentication, g-suite

I'm re-posting this thread to `Serverfault` from `Webmasters` as this is a more relevant place to ask about e-mail server related questions.

I have multiple domains that I'm managing.

Most of the cases I'm the only user.

I would like to get a single Google Apps for Work account at $5/mo for e-mail handling for all the domains.

After some researches, I've read about there are two methods for managing multiple domains: `domain alias` and `separate domain` approaches.

In my case, there's only one user myself.

I would like to have e-mail addresses for my domains such as:

```
support@domain1.com
sales@domain1.com
helpdesk@domain2.com
accounting@domain2.com
```

And be able to reply with corresponding e-mail address.

Do I use `separate domain` to set this up?

My concerns are:

1. When replying using `send as`, will viewing the `message source full header` disclose any trace of my actual user account/e-mail credential?  Or the recipient will only see the `send as` e-mail address?
2. If I'm configuring SMTP Plugin for Wordpress, do I have separate login credentials for authentication for each domain?  Or can I configure different authentication credentials for each domain?

My goal is to hide all trace of irrelevant user account info in the `message source header` as each domain should be unique entity unrelated to the others.